# "Spurts" of flame or anything else

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

Is the word "**spurts**" the correct one when we mean small bursts of something?

Can we apply this word to anything other than fire? To electricity for instance?

Comment: [Of course it's not limited to fire](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=spurts+of+*&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=).

Comment: I would not use it of electricity.  Electricity does not spurt. I would not even use it of fire, except perhaps of some flaming liquid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Spurt* can apply to anything that is liquid- or stream-like, or that flows.  Electricity can be said to "flow" or stream through wires, etc. so saying "spurts" of electricity works.

Comment: If you really think about it, it's a weird metaphor, but I agree it works.

Comment: I’ve even heard “spurts of activity”